# Random Generation of Items from Existing Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am fairly new to RoR and trying to get a basic app to work - I have a 'books' model and a 'genre' model. I wish to create a page that randomly generates books of different genre's for a user to select.

I have created a 'random_book' controller, but am unsure on how to proceed with the random selection and display.

Any help/pointers would be appreciated.

Edit:

Here's the work I've been doing in the random_book model:

" load 'user.rb'

class random_book < ActiveRecord::Base

```
 belongs_to :book
 belongs_to :genre


def get_random_book
    find(:all).sample(5)
end
```

"

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to randomly *generate* (aka create) entries in the database for that user? Or do you want to randomly *load* existing entries from the database? If you want to create, do you care if the book titles, author names and genres actually make sense?

Comment: i want to generate/create entries - but they should belong to three genre types (fiction, non-fiction, poetry). the names don't matter - I was going to use a list of random words

Comment: Is genre it's own model?

Comment: yes, I have a genre model

Comment: I don't think you need a random book model.  You already have a way to create update and display books - I would just use that, unless there is a need to store the list of random books long-term?

Comment: the user would select the book, and i hope in the future to have it added to their 'reading' list. i would need a model for that, right? or can i just work with controllers and views? thanks

Comment: Hmm... well you don't need to store the whole book information, just the fact that the user has selected it.  So what you might actually be looking for is a has_many, through: solutions.  Like.. user.books actually returns a list of books (with all the detail from the book model) but it passes through user_book, where it contains the  id of the book the id of the user, and other bits of info you might store like, whether or not the user has read the book, when they added it to the list, would they recommend it etc.

Comment: alright, this makes sense. thank you. Where would I be adding my code if the model is not needed?

Answer (score 0):

Based on discussion

4 models

1. Book
2. Genre
3. UserBook
4. User

They will look something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_books
  has_many :books, through: :user_books
end

class Genre < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :books

  def fetch_random_books(qty)
    #you want to make sure you don't error out by requesting a sample of an empty list of books so check first.  The qty argument lets you control the number of books for the search
    unless self.books.empty?
      self.books.limit(qty).sample
    end
  end
end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :genre
  has_many :user_books
end

class UserBook < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :book
end
```

I would most likely use a different route for the random book section, because it's not very url-friendly to say code-descriptive things like user_book.

There are 4 things to do

1. Create a new route to get a list of `genre_ids` that a user chooses.
2. Create an action that correlates to the route you created that renders a list of boos and adds those books to a users list
3. Create a form in a view (any view, like a sidebar in an existing books view, doesn't matter) this form will post the route and action you just made
4. Create a view to render the book list (the easy / DRY way is to add a few elements to the existing books index to let users know its a random generated list of books based on their genre pics)

Add the route

```
post "/random-books", to: "books#random_books", as: :random_books
```

Create the action in the books_controler

```
def random_books
  if params[:genre_ids]
    genres = Genre.where(id: params[:genre_ids])
    @books = []
    genres.each do |genre|
      @books << genre.fetch_random_books(10)
    end

  else
    @books = nil
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render action: :index }

  end
end
```

Then create a form that makes a `post` request to the index action of the `books_controller` -- You can parse the form and update the UserBook model inside that action, and then display list of books all at the same time.

```
<%= form_tag(random_books_path, method: :post) do %>
  <ul>
    <% Genre.all.each do |genre| %>
      <li>
      <label class='genre-select'>
        <%= check_box_tag 'genre_ids[]', genre.id -%>
        <%=  genre.name %>
      </label>

      </li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
  <%= submit_tag "Fetch Book List"%>
<% end %>
```

-- The last one I'm sure you can do, it returns a books object list so parse it however works best for you.  In the controller action you can automatically add the ids for the books to the UserBook model by adding this inside the controller action:

```
      @books.each{ |book| book.user_books.create(user: user)}
```